# What is the correct tool to automate file-transfer across a local network?

Tags: file-transfer, automation

I am a developper, and I have to replicate some code to our test server to run my code.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2.

I have developped a [mix of inotify-tools and rsync](https://github.com/GPierre-Antoine/bin/blob/master/watchChanges) :

```
rsyncWrap(){
    rsync -avzq --delete --exclude-from="$HOME/.rsyncignore" "$source" "$target"
}   

rsyncWrap
while inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete,move "$source"; do
    rsyncWrap
done
```

Note that I rely on openssh to handle the underlaying private key authentication.

but I have to make sure to launch it every time I start the computer (I tend to be quite distracted, and it seems @reboot doesn't work in my cron ...).

Furthermore, that scripts tends to behave badly in case of error (I sometimes find it in "defunct" state in `ps aux`).

What is the correct tool to accomplish that ?

Comment: Can't you just create the SSH tunnel when you call `rsyncWrap`?

Comment: I don't know what is a SSH tunnel.

Comment: You've said you have to run OpenSSH (ssh) to be able to run your rsync command...you could call your `ssh` command when your `rsyncWrap()` function is called. This means you won't need to keep the SSH open all the time (unles it's necessary to have it open all the time?)

Comment: When I say I use openssh to handle the password, I mean the variable $target is something like : remote-server:path, and I have a private key associated with that connection in my $HOME/.ssh. Is that different from what I said ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the correct tool to accomplish that ?

What you are doing is correct. `rsync` is among the best tools to use for file synchronization accross different machines, unless you have a repository you can push and pull.

> but I have to make sure to launch it every time I start the computer
>   (I tend to be quite distracted, and it seems @reboot doesn't work in
>   my cron ...).

I'd suggest you to use `systemd` here, as you can configure systemd services to run after the network starts and after you have connection. `@reboot` might not work exactly because you don't have a network connection yet (which rsync relies upon).

This is an example systemd configuration you can use:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some description
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/script
Type=oneshot
User=<user to run the script with>

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You save that configuration in `/etc/systemd/system/<service_name>.service` and run the following command:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Now if you want to enable that script to run on boot:

```
systemctl enable <service_name>.service
```

If you want to start the script manually, you can do it in your usual way or use `systemd` again:

```
systemctl start <service_name>.service
```

> Furthermore, that scripts tends to behave badly in case of error (I sometimes find it in "defunct" state in ps aux).

That might be because of rsync segmentation faults or faulty exits (which actually tends to happen quite often).

I will suggest you two things here:

**1.** Add a timeout for the rsync command, so that it doesn't hang.
**2.** Exit (?) if rsync doesn't return with exit status 0 or at least log a message so you know about it. **Or** add `-e` flag to `/bin/bash` so it exits once an error is received.

A short example on how to achieve this:

```
rsyncWrap(){
    timeout 30 rsync -avzq --delete --exclude-from="$HOME/.rsyncignore" "$source" "$target"
}   

rsyncWrap
rsync_exit_code=$?
if [ ! rsync_exit_code -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "rsync exited with exit code ${rsync_exit_code}"
done

while inotifywait -r -e modify,create,delete,move "$source"; do
    rsyncWrap
    if [ ! rsync_exit_code -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "rsync exited with exit code ${rsync_exit_code}"
    done
done
```

`timeout 30` will make sure the following command doesn't run more than 30 seconds.

References:
**1.** [How to run a single command at startup using systemd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919054/how-do-i-run-a-single-command-at-startup-using-systemd)
**2.** [systemd.Service wiki](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)
**3.** [What is bash -e flag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15998/what-does-the-e-do-in-a-bash-shebang)

Comment: Thanks, but then I have another issue : service are run as root, correct ? my private key is in my $HOME/.ssh, how do I connect the two ?

Comment: @Pierre-AntoineGuillaume They run as root **by default**. As I've added in the configuration, there is a parameter `User=`, which tells systemd which user to run the script as. Via that `User=` parameter you can tell systemd to run the service with your own user (or any other user).

Comment: great. Is there a way to support the restart as well ?

Comment: @Pierre-AntoineGuillaume which restart do you mean? Reboot of the machine?

Comment: in my previous command I meant systemctl restart <service>

Comment: Once you make it a service, `systemctl restart <service>` is already supported. You can restart it as you wish. Systemd kills (SIGTERM) the already running service and then starts it again. If you wish to do something else upon `restart`, you can add `ExecRestart=` to the configuration.

Comment: Ok so it turned out I am better off with Type=simple instead of oneshot ! thanks for your input, it helped tremendously